# How can I create a microphone preamp with a variable slew rate?

Tags: audio, microphone, preamp, slew-rate

How can I create a microphone preamp with a variable slew rate that is dialed in with a button and have a wide range from very slow to very fast?

Comment: I wonder why you would want that, slewing rate is an unwanted non-linear large-signal behavior that you want to avoid in a mic pre-amp as these are supposed to only amplify the signal.

Comment: Oh its glorious , i can explain further if you like.

Comment: I do not care about glory, otherwise I would not have become an EE ;-) A proper technical explanation I would not mind though.

Comment: How do you "dial" a button?

Comment: Well there goes the explanation , old discrete opamps were very low speed and couldnt cope with transients that well , slew rate produces some artifacts that are pleasing when someone is after a softer , warmer sound often described as vintage! I could get into more detail if you want but you already described it well enough as a non linear effect which is exactly what im after. Actually dave hill has made a top notch , super hi end pre amp *with* Variable SR to taste !

Comment: Many high-end top-of-the-line amplifiers actually are discrete opamp circuits. Even in the old days these were fast enough for audio purposes. Audio is only 20 kHz you know. For electronics that's not a big deal. I do not expect a variable slew-rate amp to satisfy your "vintage sound" needs. Then you better look for a valve amplifier. Some of these distort the audio in ways some people find pleasing. Many have tried to replicate that effect with solid-state electronics but have failed as the valve behavior is not easy to mimic in solid state. A DSP based solution might get close though.

Comment: If you can justify the efficacy of the sound produced I might have a think about it.

Comment: Good for audio doesnt mean that it wouldnt smudge a fast snare attack !

Comment: I dont think it's a broad subject as stated , i think its a very specific application actually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One obvious way to achieve slew-rate limiting is to differentiate the signal, apply variable voltage limiters (clamps) to the output of the differentiator (both positive and negative — could be symmetric or asymmetric) and then integrate the output of the limiter.

Comment: What about making it variable ?

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking for makes no sense.  When the slew rate limitation is reached, the system becomes non-linear, resulting in various distortion artifacts.  These artifacts will be triggered the more loud and high frequency a signal is.  This is not the kind of thing you want a audio circuit to do.

If you want to deliberately add distortion to create particular audio effects, then it would be better to explain what exactly those effects are.  A slew-rate limiter is a solution, not a spec.  Good engineering starts with specs, while keeping the mind open to a range of possible solutions.

All that said, to make a slew rate limiter think of driving a capacitor with a current source that can only go up to a particular current.  Once the maximum current is reached, you get a voltage signal with a fixed slope.  You'd probably put this inside a feedback loop so that the current source and capacitor affects the signal as little as possible until the current source limit is reached.  It will be tricky to keep this system stable due to the inherent pole.

Again, step back and explain the real problem, not this solution looking for a excuse to exist.

Comment: Thank you for your answer i think what you suggest is close to what im trying to achieve , i want it to be a slew rate distortion (kind of) rather than a limiter . To explain myself this is an aesthetic need! Not necessarily a scientific with proof of concept alongside , still i think its a challenge !